# Eclipse Android layout configurations for popular phones

Tags: android, eclipse

Before I ask the question let me state that I have attempted to google for this using several key words but haven't had much luck.

I am after a list of "Device Layout Configs" for the eclipse graphical layout editor. A list of popular phones, such as the Samsung Galaxy range and HTC's various desire phones is the sort of thing that I am after.

If anyone is able to point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*shameless self plug*

Looks like I need to improve my [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) a bit!

Here's a list of 'device layout configs' (Emulator Settings) for each density bucket:
http://blog.blundellapps.com/emulator-settings-for-each-android-density/

It's a start. Further reading is my list of popular devices by density bucket:
http://blog.blundellapps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/

Comment: Always willing to accept someone plugging their work if it answers the question!! This helps a lot, is there an easy way to translate those values in to values for the graphical layout editor?

Comment: @jamesakadamingo well Android works in dip for instance `android:paddingTop="10dip"` so not sure what you mean

Comment: when using the graphical editor in eclipse (creating an XML layout file) you can select various "configs" above the editor that alter how the editor displays the layout. You are able to set custom "configs", to be honest your settings for the AVD are going to help anyway, but being able to quickly switch from one config to another when designing a view would be very helpful.

Comment: @jamesakadamingo Ah not sure about that, you can select the screen size on the top left and it says Nexus One or Tablet etc thats all I know